# How to decrease the size of serverless deploy?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm deploying an aws lambda function using serverless framework. My problem is there is a [large file](https://github.com/sambaiz/puppeteer-lambda-starter-kit/blob/master/chrome/HeadlessChrome-63.0.3213.0.tar.gz) (44MB) that is deployed every time I do `sls deploy -f any_fn`. I've had similar problems when there is a `node_modules` folder (which can be quite big).

Is there a way to reduce the upload size by uploading the common files only once (and for all functions)? Because right now it keeps zipping and deploying that same binary file again and again though it never changes.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your function and it's dependencies? There might be ways to reduce its size from there.

Comment: @dashmug I've faced this problem twice, once using this project https://github.com/sambaiz/puppeteer-lambda-starter-kit (44MB) and other time using this project https://github.com/araines/serverless-php (24MB)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do what you propose. AWS Lambda requires you to upload the entire package including all dependencies each time. Everything has to be inside the zip file that is deployed to Lambda.

Comment: I thought of a way but need some input if it's feasible. What if I create a serverless proxy function, i.e. a lamba function created with serverless that accepts a file as input parameter. This function then combines this input file and with the static files (from S3 bucket) and then uses the `AWS.Lambda` nodejs API to actually deploy the function. This way I only send the function the changes only, the rest of the deployment is done via the proxy lambda function to create my new lambda function with the static files. Does that make any sense? I know it's a lot of work but will it work?

Comment: If you are just looking for something that will manage your deployments for you, so that you don't have to build and upload the final packages from your local computer, then you could use a Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery service like AWS CodePipeline.

Comment: thank you for that.. guess I'll start researching how to use AWS codepipeline to deploy my lambda functions with all those static assets to AWS lambda.

Comment: Also, follow this feature request to add S3 Transfer Acceleration to Serverless : https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4252

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution:

1. Upload the large files to S3 bucket.
2. Download all S3 files in a function executed **under the global scope**, **not in the scope**
   of `exports.handler` so the code will be executed only one time (for
   container).
3. To make sure re-use of the container you should keep
   the lambda warm using *CloudWatch* timer with [two simple steps](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0).

This allow you to deploy only the small files.

Comment: isn't there a security issue with this somehow?

Comment: @serdarsenay  issue in what part? if do you refer to the s3 bucket, then defining it as private should not be a problem. AWS has been PCI DSS Certified [since 2010](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-achieves-pci-dss-20-validated-service-provider-status/), including the service S3.

Comment: This is the best answer, upvoted, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lambda layers. All you need to do is create separate serverless project for dependencies management for ex. node_modoles and rest of the services will refer to it (follow docs). This should reduce the deployment or package size of individual lambda significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda containers and your problems will be solved! Lambda containers have a 10 GB image size limmit! You can add anything you want in there! I've made many express apps with
[Serverless http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-http)
and [lambda containers](https://www.serverless.com/blog/container-support-for-lambda).
You can also add an efs to your lambda and acess your files from there.
Check [this tutorial](https://metanube.org/2020/10/03/an-aws-summer-lambda-efs-and-the-serverless-framework/)